# How embeded/included JSP compilation takes place

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

If we have two JSPs, One main JSP and the other is the one which is embeded or included in the main JSP.

In this scenario, When JSPs are compiled, are the two JSPs compiled separately or the embeded JSP is included into main JSP first and then the main JSP compiles.

example : If i declare a variable in main JSP. can i use that variable in the included JSP?

Answer (score 0):

> If i declare a variable in main JSP. can i use that variable in the
>   included JSP?

It depends on the *scope* of the variable. The variables from the original page are local to a servlet compiled.

Learn [how to use scripting in JSP pages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnaon/index.html) or better [how to use JSP EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html).